# NestJS Testing ConfigService works

Tags: testing, mocking, nestjs

I am writing an application to handle requests and return predefined responses to allow testing of external REST endpoints by software that cannot have internal tests written into it currently.  Therefore, my code uses the Nest JS framework to handle the routes, and then extracts values and returns data.  The data returned is stored in external files.

To handle constant changes and different team usage, the program uses a .env file to give the base (root) directory where the files to respond are located.  I am trying to write a test case to ensure that the NestJS ConfigService is working properly, but also to use as a base for all my other tests.

With different routes, different data files need to be returned.  My code will need to mock all these files.  As this data relies on the base ConfigService having read the .env to find the base paths, my routes are based on this starting point.

During development, I have a local .env file with these values set.  However, I want to test without this .env file being used, so my tests do not rely on the presence of the .env file, since the CI/CD server, build server, etc., will not have a .env file.

I am simply trying a test file then to work with the configuration, to get set data from my mock.

nestjs-config.service.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

describe('NestJS Configuration .env', () => {
    let service: ConfigService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [
                ConfigModule.forRoot({
                    expandVariables: true,
                }),
            ],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: ConfigService,
                    useValue: {
                        get: jest.fn((key: string) => {
                            if (key === 'FILES') {
                                return './fakedata/';
                            } else if (key === 'PORT') {
                                return '9999';
                            }
                            return null;
                        }),
                    },
                },
            ],
        }).compile();

        service = module.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);
    });

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    it.each([
        ['FILES=', 'FILES', './', './fakedata/'],
        ['PORT=', 'PORT', '2000', '9999'],
        ['default value when key is not found', 'NOTFOUND', './', './'],
    ])('should get from the .env file, %s', (Text: string, Key: string, Default: string, Expected: string) => {
        const Result: string = service.get<string>(Key, Default);
        expect(Key).toBeDefined();
        expect(Result).toBe(Expected);
    });
});
```

The problem in this test is the default values are always returned, meaning the .env file was not read, but the provider had the code to handle this.

Ideally, I would like to create a fake class for testing so I could use it in all my test files. However, when trying to create the fake class, I get an error about other methods missing, that are unrelated to this class.

```
export class ConfigServiceFake {
    get(key: string) {
        switch (key) {
            case 'FILES':
                return './fakedata/';
            case 'PORT':
                return '9999';
        }
    }
}
```

This does not seem to execute, and it appears to still go through the original service.

Comment: read this https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing the first code snippet might help you

Comment: @MicaelLevi you pointed me in the right direction, that I was able to get it to work.  I was not implementing the jest.spyOn() properly.  It should have been `jest.spyOn(service, 'get').mockReturnValue(<data>);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to adjust this and not need external references, including importing the configuration module, making the mock simpler, and not needing the full definitions.

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

describe('NestJS Configuration .env', () => {
    let service: ConfigService;

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const FakeConfigService = {
            provide: ConfigService,
            useValue: {
                get: jest.fn((Key: string, DefaultValue: string) => {
                    switch (Key) {
                        case 'FILES':
                            return './fakedata/';
                            break;
                        case 'PORT':
                            return '9999';
                            break;
                        default:
                            return DefaultValue;
                    }
                }),
            },
        };

        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [FakeConfigService],
        }).compile();

        service = module.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);
    });

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    it.each([
        ['FILES=', 'FILES', './', './fakedata/'],
        ['PORT=', 'PORT', '2000', '9999'],
        ['default value when key is not found', 'NOTFOUND', './', './'],
    ])('should get from the .env file, %s', (Text: string, Key: string, Default: string, Expected: string) => {
        const Result: string = service.get<string>(Key, Default);
        expect(Key).toBeDefined();
        expect(Result).toBe(Expected);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Steven, I am using the same way of mocking the config service, but for some reason in one of my tests, the service is getting my mocked value, but in the other does not. It returns undefined instead. Do you have any ideas why it should be the problem?

Comment: I would assume it is not being told to use the mock instance in your other test.  In my first attempt, I was not implementing the spyOn() correctly.  Could this be your cause?

Comment: Hi @Steven, 
It was because I was also restoring all mocks in the `beforeEach`, using `jest.restoreAllMocks();`,  but still this behavior is strange.. However, it works pretty fine without it :D

Comment: You want to create the mock in BeforeAll()/BeforeEach() and then remove them in the AfterEach()/AfterAll() depending on your structure. As you found out, clearing them in the beforeEach (executed just before your test) will remove the mock you are trying to use.

Comment: Hi, @Steven,

I actually meant the `afterEach` hook, but made a typo. However, even if I used it inside the `beforeEach`, exactly before the mocking, isn't it gonna mock it anyway? I mean, clearing mocks, then create a new mock will work still, right? But in my case it was even in the `afterEach` and it still is causing problems, therefore, I left only `jest.clearAllMocks();` for now.

Comment: I know there  is some ode that is lifted in the transpiled JavaScript, so that may have some impact. Also, asynchronous code has different handling (https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown) so you need to watch  that as well when placing things in the same beforeEach().  The destruction of the mock, vs created, may have a timing issue in asynchronous code.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like that is the case. Thanks for the clarifications!